# Count (*) on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Iam little stucked with this sql query. I have got two tables

```
TbleName - usrs                     TbleName - idtb

name  |  cid                      cname   |   cid
-------------                     ----------------
james |  1100                      IT     |   1100
john  |  1200                      HR     |   1300
jack  |  1100                      QA     |   1200
bill  |  1300                      HD     |   1400
troy  |  1100


SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Total' FROM usrs u WHERE u.cid = 1100;

SELECT c.cname FROM idtb c WHERE c.cid = 1100;
```

My first query returns 3 and my second query returns IT , Now I want to join this 2 queries into one that would produe me result as this

```
        Total   |   Cname
        ------------------
          3     |    IT
```

I tried several ways and this worked

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Total',c.cname FROM usrs u JOIN  
    idtb c ON u.cid = c.cid WHERE u.cid = 1100
    GROUP BY u.cid
```

But the query does not seem to work when u.cid = 1400, since there are no names in usrs table that have cid value as 1400 and it returns empty result but I want the result to be

```
        Total   |   Cname
        -------------------
          0     |    HD
```

The query does not work if there are no records in usrs. I tried using left, right and full joins but did not figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no records for cid=1400 in the usrs table. Why would you expect it to return something different than 0?

Comment: @Aheho It does  not return the result, it does not even return Cname HD if u.cid = 1400, it just returns empty rows

Comment: You would need a left join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to print all `cname` but counting `usrs` this is the query you need:

```
select a.cname, count(b.name)
  from idtb a left join usrs b on (a.cid = b.cid)
 group by a.cname
```

If you want to add a filter for some of then, just add the where clause.

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0acec/2

Comment: @user3205479 Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Total', idtb.cname
FROM idtb LEFT JOIN usrs
ON usrs.cid=idtb.cid
WHERE usrs.cid=1100
GROUP BY idtb.cname
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will work

```
   SELECT COUNT(u.cid) as 'Total',c.cname 
   FROM usrs u left JOIN  
    idtb c ON u.cid = c.cid and u.cid = 1100
    GROUP BY u.cid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT i.cname, count(u.name) AS 'Total' 
  FROM idtb i LEFT JOIN usrs u ON (i.cid = u.cid)
 GROUP BY 1;
```

<strike>COUNT(1) is more efficient than *</strike>

I hope it works for you.

Comment: `COUNT(1)` is not more efficient than `COUNT(*)` http://stackoverflow.com/q/1221559/2186023

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've always been wrong with this one.

Comment: It was my fault. Bad sintax in the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Total', c.cname 
    FROM idtb c 
    LEFT JOIN users u
    ON u.cid = c.cid 
    GROUP BY u.cid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(u.cid) as 'Total'
     , c.cname 
FROM usrs u 
RIGHT JOIN
idtb c 
    ON u.cid = c.cid 
WHERE c.cid = 1100
GROUP BY c.cname
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this. The most simple might be using subqueries:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM usrs WHERE cid = 1100) as Total,
  cname 
FROM 
  idtb c 
WHERE 
  c.cd = 1100;
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql will let you use an entire subquery in the select list, so long as the subquery produces a [scalar value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/scalar-subqueries.html) (the subquery must return only 1 column, and ONLY 1 row).

```
select (SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Total' FROM usrs u WHERE u.cid = 1100)
     , (SELECT c.cname FROM idtb c WHERE c.cid = 1100)
```